Modern teens are cursed with medieval torture or death
I'm trying to identify a short story or novel I read in English about a group of modern teens (boys and girls both) in a modern (80s/90s) setting who are somehow cursed (be careful what you wish for? angered a magical person? not sure) to die or maybe just be severely injured "mysteriously" and supernaturally by various means of medieval torture or execution.
The one point that I remember vividly was something about "breaking on the wheel" coming up in the story, and either the story or a chapter ends with someone rushing in to report that it looks like one of the people has been "run over by some sort of wheel".
This was probably published before 1995. I can't remember a cover but I'm confident it was aimed at a teen audience.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, what was the setting (modern or medieval)? How many teens were there? What were their names? Were they all male, all female or a mixture? Why did the sorcerer dislike them? What was the name of the kingdom/place where the sorcerer came from? Did the teens have any powers or special abilities? What language did you read the story in? What did the cover look like? Was the book aimed at teens or an older audience?
